# csrf token is not working for any form action in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

CSRF token is not working for the form action in laravel 5.2 on the server.But it works in localhost.
Even i used the following code in  routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    //
});
```

Keep getting the error as follows

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
```

Please help me.

Comment: can somebody help me out..i could not able to fix this issue.Please

Comment: try using middlewareGroups instead of middleware=>web.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Http\kernel.php file. You will find the web middleware in $middlewareGroups. Which is basically a group of several middlewares including
`\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`
Read about [Middleware Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups) which is new in Laravel 5.2

So Use

`Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => 'web'], function () {
    //
});`
instead of

`Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    //
});`

**Edit:** Sad that Laravel docs mentions middleware instead of middlewareGroups.

Comment: I added even then its not working .From yesterday i was trying its not working still.

Comment: @Harshitha do you have this <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>"> in your form?

Comment: Also, as you said it's not working in server. So can you show the .env file which you're using in server?

Comment: APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:oNZORCWjnNB6ThM/b4P9Cnb6u4DjnJmg5owoU9apbsI=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mark
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
this is the .env file i m using.